# Recursion Error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, recursion

I've created two fairly simple classes in MATLAB, and I have a problem with running this.

```
classdef A

    properties
        a
    end

    methods
        function obj = A(a)
            obj.a = a;
        end
    end
end


classdef B

    properties
        b
    end

    methods
        function obj = B(b)
            obj.b = b;
        end
    end
end
```

Then, I wrote in the command window:

```
x = A(1);

y = B(x);
```

and I got the following error:

Maximum limit of 500 reached.

Why do I get this? And how should I fix it?

Comment: You constructor for `B` should be named `B` not `A` otherwise the error I get is about too many input arguments. Once you change that, I do not have any errors with what you've written. Do you have a `B` method in your `A` class or something that you're not showing us?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo when I copied my code to here. In addition, I don't have anything in my code except the above code - this my entire code

Comment: And `A.m` and `B.m` are two different files? As I said, the code as written  doesn't have any recursion in it.

Comment: Yes, they're in different files

Comment: Did you try to run this after restarting matlab?